# Error: ca-certificates is broken or not fully installed

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, certificate, dpkg

I was trying to install self-signed SSL certificate with `sudo dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates` command but before it could finish, my computer was reset due to power failure.

Now when I run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates` command, I get following error :

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates
/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: ca-certificates is broken or not fully installed
```

When I try `sudo update-ca-certificates`, I'm getting following errors :

```
sudo update-ca-certificates
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
Unknown regexp modifier "/b" at /usr/bin/c_rehash line 15, at end of line
Unknown regexp modifier "/W" at /usr/bin/c_rehash line 26, at end of line
Unknown regexp modifier "/3" at /usr/bin/c_rehash line 26, at end of line
Unknown regexp modifier "/2" at /usr/bin/c_rehash line 26, at end of line
No such class installdir at /usr/bin/c_rehash line 58, near "Prefix our installdir"
  (Might be a runaway multi-line // string starting on line 26)
syntax error at /usr/bin/c_rehash line 58, near "Prefix our installdir"
Execution of /usr/bin/c_rehash aborted due to compilation errors.
```

When I try sudo `apt install ca-certificates -f`, I'm getting following errors :

```
sudo apt install ca-certificates -f 

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
ca-certificates is already the newest version (20160104ubuntu1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up ca-certificates (20160104ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for ca-certificates (20160104ubuntu1) ...
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
Unknown regexp modifier "/b" at /usr/bin/c_rehash line 15, at end of line
Unknown regexp modifier "/W" at /usr/bin/c_rehash line 26, at end of line
Unknown regexp modifier "/3" at /usr/bin/c_rehash line 26, at end of line
Unknown regexp modifier "/2" at /usr/bin/c_rehash line 26, at end of line
No such class installdir at /usr/bin/c_rehash line 58, near "Prefix our installdir"
  (Might be a runaway multi-line // string starting on line 26)
syntax error at /usr/bin/c_rehash line 58, near "Prefix our installdir"
Execution of /usr/bin/c_rehash aborted due to compilation errors.
dpkg: error processing package ca-certificates (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 255
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ca-certificates
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Because of this, I can't even push my work to Git repo. I'm getting following error when I try to do so :

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/***/***-tdd.git/': Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)
```

Does anyone know how to fix this without me having to reinstall Ubuntu all over again? Kindly help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there's a bug in the c_rehash perl script (I'm getting similar errors and I found this discussion: https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/icaclient/?comments=all).  In /bin/c_rehash on my system (archlinux, looks like yours is in /usr/bin/c_rehash) there are some quotes missing.  I had to change this (near the top of the file):

```
my $dir = /etc/ssl;
my $prefix = /usr;
```

to:

```
my $dir = "/etc/ssl";
my $prefix = "/usr";
```

and then it worked.

Answer (score 7):

In my case, a wrong closing of the ca-certificates setup led to a broken file.
Reinstalling/updating 'debconf' solved my problem:

```
sudo apt-get install debconf
```